# Find pairs of numbers in an array or List

Tags: c#, arrays

My goal is to find pairs of numbers in an array or List. A pair in this case is defined by the maximum difference between two entries. For instance

```
1
50
2
100
102
800
```

Pairs(if max difference threshold is 2) with line numbers(array number):

```
1,2 line number of 1 is 0
100,101 line number of 100 is 3
```

How do I do this?

Comment: These are very simple actions which only need a quite straightforward algorithm. Additionally, when working with .NET, relying on external libraries is the exception not the rule. And on top of everything "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." is off-topic here.

Comment: Instead of asking about common libraries to your problem, why don't you just ask how to solve your problem directly?

Comment: Beside what was said before, this question is already answered multiple times on stackoverflow and searching for them should be easy!

Comment: @varocarbas Thank you man, you made be a better human being.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I corrected it.

Comment: ?! I use this site (or any other one) as intended. If a more experienced person show me how to use it properly, I would just learn. If I am asking a question about something (presumably because of not knowing too much about it), I would also be thankful to anyone trying to help me (rather than ignoring them). Finally, if I don't have almost any knowledge about something, would certainly expect a specialised forum to not take my clueless requests too seriously. Not sure whether all this means that I am a better human being, but certainly a practical, understanding and keen-on-learning one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to do this:

```
var numbers = new[]
{
    1,
    50,
    2,
    100,
    102,
    800
};

var treshold = 2;

var numWithIndexes = numbers.Select((value, index) => new { value, index });

var pairs = from num1 in numWithIndexes
            from num2 in numWithIndexes
            where (num2.value - num1.value <= treshold) && (num2.value - num1.value > 0)
            select new[]
        {
            num1.value, // first number in the pair
            num2.value, // second number in the pair
            num1.index, // index of the first number in the pair
            num2.index  // index of the second member in the pair
        };

foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pair found: " + pair[0] + ", " + pair[1] +
                      " at line " + pair[2] + ", " + pair[3]);
}
```

Comment: I added a foreach loop to print the found pairs, for me it works as it should. Could you please provide the numbers you are using for testing?

Comment: Thanks. If I wanted to get the index of the other number aswell, what would I change? I tried http://pastebin.com/bgwAJUWR but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There rather is no library, you can sort array and then itterayt in loop to find pairs.

Comment: The the cost of operation then will be less then in other way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any library that would help you with this. You can use the methods in the framework.

For the case where threshold is 1, if you put the numbers from the array in a hash set you can efficiently look up the numbers that is a part of a pair:

```
HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>(myArray);
int[] pairs = myArray.Where(i => set.Contains(i + 1)).ToArray();
```

The `pairs` array will have the lower number of the pairs, e.g. `{ 1, 100 }` when the pairs are `1, 2` and `100, 101`.

To get the index instead of the number, iterate the indexes instead:

```
HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>(myArray);
int[] index = Enumerable.Range(myArray.Length).Where(i => set.Contains(myArray[i + 1])).ToArray();
```

The `index` array will have the index of the lower numbers of the pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Easily solved by sorting and then using a simple loop:

```
FindPairs(sequence: new[] { 1, 50, 2, 100, 101, 800 }, threshold: 2); // {1, 2}, {100, 101}.

private List<int[]> FindPairs(IEnumerable<int> sequence, int threshold)
{
    var sorted = sequence.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

    var pairs = new List<int[]>();
    for (var i = 0; i < sorted.Count - 1; ++i)
    {
        if (sorted[i + 1] - sorted[i] <= threshold)
        {
            pairs.Add(new [] { sorted[i], sorted[i + 1] });
        }
    }

    return pairs;
}
```